# Comparing Sorting Algorithms

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I am trying to compare some sorting algorithms and i would like to run them all at the same time and get the time to sort, numbwe of swaps and comparisons.  I have these 2 algorithms:

```
def bubble_sort(nums):
    swapped = True
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
            if nums[i] > nums[i + 1]:
                nums[i], nums[i + 1] = nums[i + 1], nums[i]
                swapped = True


def selection_sort(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        lowest_value_index = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
            if nums[j] < nums[lowest_value_index]:
                lowest_value_index = j
        nums[i], nums[lowest_value_index] = nums[lowest_value_index], nums[i]
        return nums
```

I would like to run them so sort a list of  10, 100 and 1000 integers, 10 times each. and as a result i would like to have the mean time to process, swaps and comparions made by both algorithms.

```
ten_ = np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=10)
hundred_ = np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=100)
thous_ = np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=1000)


sort_algorithms = (
        bubble_sort,
        selection_sort)

for algo in sort_algotithms:
```

i am lost here:  I want to sort the ten_, hundred_, thous_ list to get the metrics: time, swaps, comparisons

Can someone help me here?

Comment: You'll need to modify your sorting functions to compute the number of swaps and comparisons

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to time your functions you can use the `time` library

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
bubble_sort(ten_)
end_time = time.time() - start_time
```

There is no easy trick to count the number of comparisons and swaps: you have to add a bit of code in the function to count them. For example:

```
def bubble_sort(nums):
    swapped = True
    compares = 0
    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
            compares += 1
            if nums[i] > nums[i + 1]:
                nums[i], nums[i + 1] = nums[i + 1], nums[i]
                swapped = True

    return nums, compares
```

Also, you want to watch out when you pass a mutable object(lists, dictionaries, numpy arrays for example) into a function. Your function will modify the variable outside the function. For example:

```
print(ten_)
bubble_sort(ten_)
print(ten_)
```

the print function returned different values for the same variable, even though you didn't explicitly change it. To avoid this, add a line `nums = nums.copy()` at the beginning of the function

Comment: I agree with almost everything you say, except use of time to measure code performance.  The recommended method is to use the timeit library.  See [Measure Time in Python – time.time() vs time.clock()](https://www.pythoncentral.io/measure-time-in-python-time-time-vs-time-clock/) for why this is a better approach.